# Lambda can change the reference but fun cannot in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    var str = "hello"
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        changeRef(str){
            str = "Tarun"
        }
    }
    println(str)
}

fun changeRef(str : String,ref : (String) -> Unit){
    ref(str)
}
fun lambdaFoo(str : String){
    str = "Tarun"
}
```

changeRef() with the help of the lambda changed the str variable to "Tarun" but lambdaFoo() is a compile time error. What is the difference in passing arguments to a lambda and function?

Comment: Side note, lambdas can change references from the outer scope if they are passed to higher-order inline functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a difference in passing arguments, your lambda is very different from the `fun`: it ignores its argument and accesses `str` from the outer scope.

If you tried to write an equivalent of `lambdaFoo`, it would be

```
changeRef(str) {
    it = "Tarun"
}
```

or

```
changeRef(str) { str ->
    str = "Tarun"
}
```

which will both be compilation errors.

Or you could write a fun equivalent to your lambda:

```
var str = "Hello"
fun lambdaFoo(notStr: String) {
    str = "Tarun"
}
```